Автотестирование UXUI с помощью Appium (моб. игра на Unity)
Для тестирования интерфейса мобильной игры на C# планирую внедрить отдельные от Unity автотесты. Тесты разрабатываются с использованием NUnit v4.2.1 и Appium.WebDriver v4.4.5.(.NET Framework 4.8 с зависимостями: Castle.Core (>= 4.3.1), DotNetSeleniumExtras.PageObjects (>= 3.11.0), Newtonsoft.Json (>= 13.0.1), Selenium.Support (>= 3.141.0) и Selenium.WebDriver (>= 3.141.0)). Следующий этап — это прямое подключение тестов к мобильному устройству через USB для выполнения на реальном девайсе. Возникла проблема с тем, что Appium Inspector некорректно распознает элементы верстки — вместо индивидуальных элементов видит их как единый объект, что связано с невозможностью доступа к xPath. Соответственно обращаться к объектам не получится. Есть ли еще какие-то варианты подключения теста без доступа к исходному коду? Поделитесь, пожалуйста

Unity просто рисует картинку на экране, там технически нет никаких UI элементов. Поэтому вариант только тыркать по координатам на экране. Ну или искать/использовать заточенные под Unity инструменты.
